# Add div tag to existing rendered html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have div with multiple tags in it. I want to add the  with so i can convert my existing to bootstrap grid view. Here is my html as below:

```html
<div class="render-wrap" id="fb-render-wrap">
    <div class="fb-text form-group customdiv col-md-12 field-text-1505825076921">
        <label for="text-1505825076921" class="fb-text-label">Name<span class="fb-required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" name="text-1505825076921" id="text-1505825076921" required="required" aria-required="true" data-msg="Name is requird.">
    </div>
    <div class="fb-date form-group customdiv col-md-12 field-date-1505825086301">
        <label for="date-1505825086301" class="fb-date-label">From Date<span class="fb-required">*</span></label>
        <input type="date" name="date-1505825086301" id="date-1505825086301" required="required" aria-required="true" data-msg="From Date is requird.">
    </div>   
</div>
```

And I want the output as below:

```html
<div class="render-wrap" id="fb-render-wrap">
    <div class="fb-text form-group customdiv col-md-12 field-text-1505825076921">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label for="text-1505825076921" class="fb-text-label">Name<span class="fb-required">*</span></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <input type="text" name="text-1505825076921" id="text-1505825076921" required="required" aria-required="true" data-msg="Name is requird.">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="fb-date form-group customdiv col-md-12 field-date-1505825086301">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label for="date-1505825086301" class="fb-date-label">From Date<span class="fb-required">*</span></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <input type="date" name="date-1505825086301" id="date-1505825086301" required="required" aria-required="true" data-msg="From Date is requird.">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried to iterate through div using customdiv css but don't know how to append the div.

```
$('.customdiv').children().each(function () {
  if ($(this).prop("tagName").toLowerCase() == "label") {
    $(this).prepend('<div class="col-md-3">');
    $(this).append("</div>");
  } else {
    $(this).prepend('<div class="col-md-5">');
    $(this).append("</div>");
  }
});
```

Somebody help me out to achieve this in best way.

Comment: Are you getting any exception?

Comment: You don’t want to append or prepend - you want to **wrap**. http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Comment: And FYI, append/prepend don’t work that way to begin with - you can not use them to append single opening or closing HTML _tags_, but only complete elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a div and append the child and then add the new element into the parent, so that you can achieve your result html

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".form-group").each(function(i, obj) {
    var tt = $('<div class="col-md-3"></div>');
    $(tt).append($(obj).find("label"));
    $(obj).append(tt);
    var tt = $('<div class="col-md-5"></div>');
    $(tt).append($(obj).find("input, select, textarea"));
    $(obj).append(tt);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="render-wrap" id="fb-render-wrap">
  <div class="fb-text form-group customdiv col-md-12 field-text-1505825076921">
    <label for="text-1505825076921" class="fb-text-label">Name<span class="fb-required">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" name="text-1505825076921" id="text-1505825076921" required="required" aria-required="true" data-msg="Name is requird.">
  </div>
  <div class="fb-date form-group customdiv col-md-12 field-date-1505825086301">
    <label for="date-1505825086301" class="fb-date-label">From Date<span class="fb-required">*</span></label>
    <input type="date" name="date-1505825086301" id="date-1505825086301" required="required" aria-required="true" data-msg="From Date is requird.">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This work fine but each time there will not be `input` tag as second tag it change to `select, textarea` as per control i have created.

Comment: then change the input to `input, select, textarea`. updated the answer now

Answer (score 1):

Have a look:

```js
$('.customdiv').children().each(function () {
  if ($(this).is('label')) {
      $(this).wrap('<div class="col-md-3"></div>');
  } else {
      $(this).wrap('<div class="col-md-5"></div>');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="render-wrap" id="fb-render-wrap">
    <div class="fb-text form-group customdiv col-md-12 field-text-1505825076921">
        <label for="text-1505825076921" class="fb-text-label">Name<span class="fb-required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" name="text-1505825076921" id="text-1505825076921" required="required" aria-required="true" data-msg="Name is requird.">
    </div>
    <div class="fb-date form-group customdiv col-md-12 field-date-1505825086301">
        <label for="date-1505825086301" class="fb-date-label">From Date<span class="fb-required">*</span></label>
        <input type="date" name="date-1505825086301" id="date-1505825086301" required="required" aria-required="true" data-msg="From Date is requird.">
    </div>   
</div>
```